# LocomotiveJS Server Port Change

Tags: node.js, express, locomotivejs

I am using locomotivejs for my node project. When I fire the lcm server command locomotive listen to port 3000 as default. I tried to change it but nothig worked. I thin I am missing something. From where should I change the listened port for lcm server command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a the port as an option to the `lcm` command using `-p`, as such:

```
lcm server -p 1234
```

Ref: The source [never lies](https://github.com/jaredhanson/locomotive/blob/master/bin/lcm.js#L17) ; )

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me :) By the way is there a way to change the default from 3000 to another value

Comment: Not other than creating a bash alias or editing the source directly to change the default : )

Comment: Also, if this solution worked, make sure to mark it as correct so that if anyone else finds this question they will know!

Comment: Ok I am marking it now :D I tried a couple of time to change the default by editing the source but It didnt worked, do u have any idea about this ?

Comment: I would not recommend editing the source, honestly. I would make an alias in your bash profile like `alias lcms="lcm server -p 1234"`

Answer (score 0):

Jeff right, you could use following command:

```
lcm server -p [port_number]
```

where [port_number] is the port you want to use.

Other approach is to set `env` variable `PORT` and it'll do the same. 
Probably you'll find interesting following way to get more information about `server` command:

```
lcm server -h
```